# Playing sound on Ubuntu server without a physical sound card

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a server with Ubuntu server 16.04 installed, which doesn't have a physical sound card.

Is it possible to play sound (over VGA, HDMI,...) without the sound card?
Do I have to install a virtual sound card or something?

I've installed alsa, alsa-tools, pulseaudio and tried to play with both MOC and via a movie using mplayer.

Comment: You can use a dummy output, but no sou d without some sound card, built into the mobo or separate, and some sort of speaker or headphone. You can stream auduo

Comment: is it possible to install an external sound card via usb or something?

Comment: Yes I have used usb sound cards with linux. Just get a linux compatible usb